# "Have helped" or "helped"?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

> you have helped me (Present Perfect)
>   you helped me (Past Simple)

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: May I redirect you to the Stack Exchange community for English language learners? https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Certainly not "helpes".

Comment: They are both correct. As you say yourself, these are two different tenses. This is like asking which is correct: "I have helped you" or "I will help you". Both are correct. They just mean different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone says "you have helped me," they typically convey that the help persists into the present. "You helped me" indicates that the help was in the past, and that help may or may not continue to help now.

If someone gave you good advice that you continue to use in the present, you would probably say, "you have helped me." If someone came and rescued you when you had a flat tire, you'd probably say, "you helped me."

Comment: No problem. If my answer is the answer you are going with, feel free to mark it as such. If it isn't, hopefully you'll find an answer soon.